# Segmentation Fault during Django page render on Mac

Tags: python, django, segmentation-fault, django-cms

- Mac 10.14.3
- Python 3.6.5 (also tried 3.7.2) installed via homebrew
- Django==1.11.20
- django-cms==3.5.3
- sqlite3 3.24.0

Things seem to run fine on my production (linux) server. Issue is only on my mac when developing.

Running with

```
./venv/bin/python3 -Xfaulthandler manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Migrations run fine, but page render segfaults:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 17, 2019 - 08:04:34
Django version 1.11.20, using settings 'project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x000070000864d000 (most recent call first):
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328 in execute
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64 in execute
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79 in execute
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 889 in execute_sql
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53 in __iter__
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/utils/plugins.py", line 284 in downcast_plugins
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/utils/plugins.py", line 75 in <genexpr>
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/utils/plugins.py", line 75 in assign_plugins
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/plugin_rendering.py", line 529 in _preload_placeholders_for_page
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/plugin_rendering.py", line 329 in render_page_placeholder
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py", line 309 in render_tag
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/classytags/core.py", line 153 in render
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 72 in render
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py", line 444 in render_tag
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/classytags/core.py", line 153 in render
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sekizai/templatetags/sekizai_tags.py", line 93 in render_tag
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/classytags/core.py", line 153 in render
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177 in render
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207 in render
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66 in render
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 84 in rendered_content
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 107 in render
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215 in _get_response
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249 in _legacy_get_response
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41 in inner
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124 in get_response
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 157 in __call__
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137 in run
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 155 in handle
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 696 in __init__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 361 in finish_request
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 639 in process_request_thread
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864 in run
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x0000000109d415c0 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/selectors.py", line 376 in select
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 236 in serve_forever
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174 in run
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 148 in inner_run
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 111 in run
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 100 in handle
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330 in execute
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61 in execute
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283 in run_from_argv
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356 in execute
  File "<local_dir>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364 in execute_from_command_line
  File "manage.py", line 11 in <module>
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Is this a sqlite3 error? Something else? I'm not sure which thread caused the segfault.

Comment: Are you running Django Debug Toolbar by any chance? I've run into SegFaults between DjDT and Wagtail in the past. Possibly something similar? https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/4249

Comment: Nope. Not using django debug toolbar.

Comment: I know there have been some issues with SQLite recently - a newer version was causing problems, but I'm unable to find the discussion, sorry. One other thought to test; try running `runserver` without threading: `python manage.py runserver --nothreading` and see if that does anything? Does this segfault also occur on a simple view, for example, a `TemplateView` that just renders `<h1>Hello World</h1>`?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. with `--nothreading` the only error is the sqlite stacktrace. I put a `url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="test.html"), name='home'),` at the top of my urls, and that page did render/200, so it does appear to be something wrong with the db connection.

Comment: If you figure it out, answer your own question, for sure. I'd recommend trying previous versions of SQLite. Try `pip install sqlite3<3.24`, then `pip install sqlite3<3.23`, etc. Give it a try with a few previous versions. I remember something being mentioned on the Django developers list about new SQLite versions causing issues, but can't find the thread.

Comment: It seems as though installing a different version of sqlite3 is not an easy task since it's built into python. `pip install sqlite3` does not point to a package available in pip, and changing the `pysqlite3` version from 0.2.1 to anything else seems to not change the version when i run `$ python ... import sqlite3; sqlite3.sqlite_version`

Comment: @FlipperPA is https://bugs.python.org/issue36073 what you were referring to?

Comment: I believe that is it, thanks @KFunk!